# UnicodeDecodeError issue while looping through all the pictures in a folder using CV2

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

My code:

```
folder_angry = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/test'
all_vald_img = []
    
for filename_valid in os.listdir(folder_angry):
    img_valid = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder_angry,filename_valid))
    if img_valid is not None:
        all_vald_img.append(img_valid)

    true_image = image.load_img(img_valid)
    img = image.load_img(img_valid, color_mode="grayscale", target_size=(48, 48))
```

Error message:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I encountered this error while looping through the entire folder of pictures using cv2.imread. I've tried solutions like

```
with open(path, 'rb') as f:
  contents = f.read()
```

or any other solutions start with `with open` like many people suggested, but none of them really works. However, if I use picture one by one without loop, like

```
filename_valid = "path"
true_image = image.load_img(filename_valid)
img = image.load_img(filename_valid, color_mode="grayscale", target_size=(48, 48))
```

it works, but I have to do it one by one.

Is there any good way to tackle this down?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are passing the image itself (as NumPy array) to `image.load_img`, while `image.load_img` expects an image file name as argument.

Basically you are trying to read each image twice:

- Using OpenCV:
  `cv2.imread` returns an image (as NumPy array) in case of successful reading, and return `None` when reading fails.
- Using Pillow:
  `image.load_img(file_name)` loads the image using Pillow, and returns an object of type `PIL.Image.Image`.

The issue is that `image.load_img` expects a file name as an argument, and you are passing it an image (NumPy array) instead of file name.
The NumPy array is not a valid 'utf-8' string, so you are getting the error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfd in position 1: invalid start byte.

---

Assuming that reading each image twice is not an issue...
You may use something like the following code sample:

```
import os
import cv2
from keras.preprocessing import image


folder_angry = 'C:/Users/User/Desktop/test'
all_vald_img = []
all_vald_img_files = []
    
for filename_valid in os.listdir(folder_angry):
    image_file_name = os.path.join(folder_angry,filename_valid)
    img0 = cv2.imread(image_file_name)  # Return the image as NumPy array in case of valid reading, and None if not valid.
    if img0 is not None:
        all_vald_img_files.append(image_file_name)  # Append file name to the list (not the image).

        true_image = image.load_img(image_file_name)  # Use file name as argument to image.load_img
        img = image.load_img(image_file_name, color_mode="grayscale", target_size=(48, 48))
        all_vald_img.append(img)

# Showing images in all_vald_img for testing:
for img in all_vald_img:
    img.show()
```

---

Note: I was guessing that you want to keep only the images loaded by `image.load_img`.